# Problem with wolfram alpha equation?

Tags: expression-test

Giving this as to test the equation results in "False":

[image]

But simply changing the upper level on the divider, it results in true

[image]

What gives?

Answer (score 5):

Simplification is not done by default.
Moreover, `==` ([`Equal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html?q=Equal)) and `===` ([`SameQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html)) are not the same.

```
FullSimplify[(a == (a r - a)/(r - 1))]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

You might not think you are expected to understand these subtleties of *Wolfram Language*, as *Wolfram Alpha* is meant as a human interpreter. However, by using `===` you are just misleading the interpreter. If you would use `=`, you also get the expected result.